# Can't Read Updated ASP.NET Textbox on Submit

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webform that populates textboxes from a database. The user then changes values in the forms (i.e. password) and pressed the submit button to update his account information. The problem here is that when data is changed in the textboxes, the method below doesn't read the changed values but only sees the original values. I'm not sure why Textbox_field.Text wouldn't retrieve the current values of the control.

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried using IsPostback but didn't have any success with it.

Thanks.

```
protected void Button_Save_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (_connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open ();

            string firstName = TextBox_FirstName.Text; 
            string lastName = TextBox_LastName.Text; 
            string email = TextBox_Email.Text;
            string login = TextBox_Username.Text;
            string password = TextBox_Password.Text;
            int userID = Convert.ToInt32 (Session ["UserID"]); 

            string sql = "update Auth_Users"                           
                       + $"    set FirstName='{firstName}', LastName='{lastName}', Email='{email}', Login='{login}', Password='{password}'"                            
                       + $" where ID={userID}"; 

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sql, conn))                 
            {                   
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery ();                
            } 

            conn.Close ();          
      }
}
```

Comment: Search for proper sql update statement. This syntax `'{firstName}'`, etc. is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "update Auth_Users set FirstName=@FirstNAme, LastName=@LastName"                            
                       + " where ID=@UserId"; 

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sql, conn))                 
            { 
                 command.parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName) 
                 command.parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName) 
                 command.parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userID) 
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery ();                
            }
```